# CPU Frequency Scaling in Unity?

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, cpufreq

In Ubuntu 10.10, I added the CPU scaling applet on my panel in order to control the CPU frequency scaling. Since Unity no longer has a panel that supports applets, what mechanism do I use in 11.04 to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a special app-indicator, Cpufreq.

[image: App-Indicator]

[**Install Indicator-Cpufreq**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/37997#37997)

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: It's unfortunate that it's neither a part of ubuntu (a PPA), nor something that can be added easily (without running alt-f2).

Comment: @Mike You could add it to your `startup applications` so you don't have to start it every time

Comment: the only thing this app lets me choose from is powersave and performance. nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a program called jupiter.

[image: Jupiter]

Download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/files/

1. 3 perfomance mode
2. disable wifi/bluetooth/touchpad
3. change screen resolutions
4. rotate the display

Comment: the question asks explicitly for something that works with indicators.

Comment: The question does not include "indicator". Question asks for a "mechanism". Nevertheless it does what is asked for and works better than any other I have used.

Comment: I think it is a good answer because it makes people aware of more/other alternatives that may suit them better. Even if I do agree with that the answer mentioning the indicator is superior, IMHO.

Comment: ok fine, the question explicitly asks for something that works outside gnome-panel, or rather, something that works with Unity. Your screeshot looks nothing like Unity.

Comment: Btw there is a PPA for this: `ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`

Answer (score 0):

you can also create a launcher. Right click on desktop, select "create launcher" name it, icon it, and put "indicator-cpufreq" as the command. then drag it to the unity launcher. I have a folder in home which keeps my desktop free of launcher clutter while the applet war wraps up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered already, but I found [this link](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/07/cpu-frequency-scaling-indicator-on.html) very easy to install the CPU Frequency Scaling.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.