# CPU Scaling in Unity with indicator-cpufreq

Tags: 11.04, unity, cpufreq

Original question by some guy:
 [CPU Frequency Scaling in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35238/cpu-frequency-scaling-in-unity)

Followup:
I installed the **indicator-cpufreq** app and ran it, but nothing appears in my indicator are. I can see that the app is running with ps -A|grep cpufreq. I tried running it with sudo as well, but no dice. Trying to run the app with -v for verbose gives no extra output either.

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be an icon issue.  Try running the following:

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
```