# CPU frequency scaling for 12.04?

Tags: power-management

In 10.10, I remember I had CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor by default. Now in 12.04, I cannot find anything similar in Ubuntu software center. I wonder what applications are recommended for scaling CPU frequency in 12.04, and how to get and install them?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/35238/cpu-frequency-scaling-in-unity There is a package Tim in Launchpad =)

Comment: Does look like a dup.

Comment: @wojox: why can't I find cpufreq in Ubuntu software center? Is there something similar to synaptic software manager in 12.04?

Comment: Here Tim http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/37997#37997

Comment: @wojox: You mean "ppa:artfwo/ppa"? How shall I use this information to get cpufreq?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`indicator-cpufreq` can be found in the Software Center by searching "cpu frequency" and then clicking on the "show technical items" option:

[image]

And this is what it looks like, to compare what you were used to in 10.04:

[image]

- Note that you may need to put it in startup if you don't wish to start it manually every time -- usually it should go into Startup Applications automatically, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I found and installed it. My laptop has two cores. indicator-cpufreq seems just give options for one core, or the options are for both cores? In 10.10, I have two identical groups of choices, each group for each core.

Comment: I believe the options are for both cores, i.e. it will set both cores at the same time to the same parameters. You would need to use `cpufrequtils` from the terminal if you want finer per-core control.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to show real-time CPU frequency? In 10.10, the CPU frequency monitor can both show it and scale it.

Comment: I also found that after restart, the setting of CPU frequency is back to "on demand". Can I set it once until I change it by myself?

Comment: Are there any command line options?

Answer (score 4):

I use indicator-cpufreq on Unity. It seems very parallel to what I use with 10.10. You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot find Unity. Where is it?

Comment: I searched it on http://unity.ubuntu.com/, but it is not found.

Comment: Unity is just the user interface (by default) on 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little bit of research and found [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706) that explains how to use `cpulimit` to set the maximum consumption for a particular process. It runs as a daemon that will monitor all processes.

Answer (score 2):

This what I use to set the frequency of CPU in Ubuntu 12.04.

If you want to have control of CPU frequency in Ubuntu 12.04, do this:

- open Ubuntu software center or synaptic software manager
- Install awn-settings (this is a dock)
- Now open awn settings and set to start-awn automatically
- Restart computer
- Now you must have the dock on the bottom of desktop

  - Right click Dock preferences
  - Go on to Applets tab.
  - In the **Categories** section select **Monitor** and from right section **Available Applets** double click on CPU Frequency monitor to add on dock.