# Limit overall cpu usage Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, cpu, overheating, resource-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CPU frequency scaling for 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142688/cpu-frequency-scaling-for-12-04)

I was wondering if there is a way to limit the total cpu usage percentage? I know that you can limit the usage per process with cpulimit but I'm looking for a way to cap the maximum usage for all processes.

For example, in windows you can change the cpu percentage in advanced power options. I'm looking for a feature or app similar to this.

My laptop overheats if any process uses more than 80% of the cpu and so this is a real problem for me. I have jupiter installed and it works fine in power saving mode but I would like a bit more control over how much the cpu is limited.

Thanks in advance