# How can I use CPU-Freq Indicator?

Tags: 12.04, cpufreq

**Translated:** 
I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I can not use indicator-cpufreq,

Does anybody know of any others?

**Original Question**
Me pase a ubuntu 12.04 y ya no puedo usar indicator-cpufreq, conoceis algun otro para que funcione?

Comment: Welcome Dion0396:  (Por favor,Inglés) This is an English speaking site and I have translated your question, however we need more details about what your are asking?

Comment: Here is your answer:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/142688/cpu-frequency-scaling-for-12-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use `indicator-multiload`.

Install it from the Ubuntu Software Center or using the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

[image]

You can configure some of the things from the **Preferences**.

Answer (score 2):

`indicator-multiload` doesn't have the same functionality as `indicator-cpufreq` to control the CPU frequency. After doing a lot of research I couldn't get `indicator-cpufreq` to work with Ubuntu 12.04. Finally I found Jupiter and it works well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Answer (score 1):

for `indicator-multiload` you can also add cpu freq:

Preferences -> Menu items -> add

`$(frequency(cpufreq.cur0)) - $(percent(cpu.cpu0.inuse))`
`$(frequency(cpufreq.cur1)) - $(percent(cpu.cpu1.inuse))`

etc...

[frequency in menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cQT8.png)