# What is throttling multithreaded performance?

Tags: performance

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 (64 bit) on a Dell T5500 with two Xeon 5650 6-core processors specifically to run the free DCP-o-matic software (http://dcpomatic.com/). The same machine used all 24 virtual cores before under Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, but I was just not happy with that OS.

Under Ubuntu the performance was less than 1/10 of what I had experienced under Windows. I next upgraded to 14.04.2 but to no avail. Monitoring the resources makes it clear that the processors are throttled down after reaching their peak performance. The pattern looks like saw teeth.

Here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]

What can I do to achieve maximum performance? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: That just shows that the program is doing bursts of activity with little to no activity between.  There are a million reasons this could be, including the program being poorly designed, or it is simply waiting on disk IO.  It has nothing to do with cpu frequency scaling or "throttling".

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely then not due to CPU scaling.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

[CPU frequency scaling for 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142688/cpu-frequency-scaling-for-12-04)

https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling

You can set your governer to performance

GOVERNOR="performance"

http://www.servernoobs.com/avoiding-cpu-speed-scaling-in-modern-linux-distributions-running-cpu-at-full-speed-tips/

Personally I would set it back to ondemand once you are done using it